# Get dates in a millisecond range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table in SQL Server

```
[ArticleID] - number
[ArticleName] - varchar
[Created_dtm] - date
[Update_dtm] - date
```

I would like to get all rows where Created_dtm are in 0,1 - 1,5 seconds before Update_dtm.

I've tried with

```
Select *
from [Article]
Where ([Created_dtm] + 0.1 < [Update_dtm]) or ([Created_dtm] + 1.5 < [Update_dtm])
```

But it does not work. im lost

Comment: If they're declared as a `DATE`, this is literally impossible.  Do you mean they are `DATETIME`?

Comment: my bad, they are [datetime] NOT NULL,

Comment: If you need that level of resolution, defining [Created_dtm] & [Update_dtm] as DATE data types isn't going to cut it. I suggest using DATETIME2(4) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys

Comment: How are the dates stored? Do you use all the way down to the millisecond? ie Dates stored as xx:xx:xx.150 or xx:xx:xx.999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using milliseconds:

```
Select *
from [Article]
Where (dateadd(ms, 100, Created_dtm) > [Update_dtm]) and
      (dateadd(ms, 1500, Created_dtm) < [Update_dtm])
```

Or write out the full name of the time part:

```
Select *
from [Article]
Where dateadd(millisecond, 100, Created_dtm) > [Update_dtm] and
      dateadd(millisecond, 1500, Created_dtm) < [Update_dtm]
```

Comment: Watch out for datetime precision errors. Also, the range in the `WHERE` is exclusive. It needs to be >= and <=

Answer (score 2):

When you're working with `datetime`s, especially in the millisecond range, you have to be *very* cognizant of the precision of your `datetime` field. In MS SQL, a `datetime` datatype is only accurate to 1/300th of a second. This means that high precision will result in some unexpected rounding. This is one of the main reasons that even Microsoft suggests that `datetime2` be used instead of `datetime`.

**SETUP**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#times') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #times ;

CREATE TABLE #times ( pickMe varchar(5), Created_dtm datetime, Update_dtm datetime ) ;

INSERT INTO #times ( pickMe, Created_dtm, Update_dtm )
VALUES 
      ( 'YES', '9/6/2017 12:00:00.000' , '9/6/2017 12:00:01.250' ) -- 1.25
    , ( 'YES', '9/6/2017 12:00:00.000' , '9/6/2017 12:00:00.100' ) -- 0.1
    , ( 'YES', '9/6/2017 12:00:00.000' , '9/6/2017 12:00:01.500' ) -- 1.5
    , ( 'NO' , '9/6/2017 12:00:00.000' , '9/6/2017 12:00:00.099' ) -- 0.099
    , ( 'NO' , '9/6/2017 12:00:00.000' , '9/6/2017 12:00:01.501' ) -- 1.501

    , ( 'NO' , '9/6/2017 12:00:00.000' , '9/6/2017 14:00:00.000' ) -- WAY OUT

    , ( 'YES', '9/6/2017 11:59:59.500' , '9/6/2017 12:00:00.000' ) -- 0.5
    , ( 'YES', '9/6/2017 11:59:59.900' , '9/6/2017 12:00:00.000' ) -- 0.1   
    , ( 'YES', '9/6/2017 11:59:58.500' , '9/6/2017 12:00:00.000' ) -- 1.5
    , ( 'NO' , '9/6/2017 11:59:59.901' , '9/6/2017 12:00:00.000' ) -- 0.099
    , ( 'NO' , '9/6/2017 11:59:58.499' , '9/6/2017 12:00:00.000' ) -- 1.501

    , ( 'NO' , '9/6/2017 10:00:00.000' , '9/6/2017 12:00:00.000' ) -- WAY OUT
;
```

In my examples, I picked a lot of edge dates that show the rounding problems. This should `SELECT` records that have a `Created_dtm` that is between .1 and 1.5 seconds before the `Modified_dtm`, only 6 of them.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT
      DATEDIFF(millisecond,Created_dtm,Update_dtm) AS diff
    , pickMe
    , Created_dtm
    , Update_dtm
FROM #times
WHERE DATEADD(millisecond, 100, Created_dtm) <= update_dtm
    AND DATEADD(millisecond, 1500, Created_dtm) >= Update_dtm
```

This returns

```
| diff | pickMe |         Created_dtm         |          Update_dtm         |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1250 |  YES   |   2017-09-06 12:00:00.000   |   2017-09-06 12:00:01.250   |
| 100  |  YES   |   2017-09-06 12:00:00.000   |   2017-09-06 12:00:00.100   |
| 1500 |  YES   |   2017-09-06 12:00:00.000   |   2017-09-06 12:00:01.500   |
| 100  |   NO   |   2017-09-06 12:00:00.000   | **2017-09-06 12:00:00.100** |
| 1500 |   NO   |   2017-09-06 12:00:00.000   | **2017-09-06 12:00:01.500** |
| 500  |  YES   |   2017-09-06 11:59:59.500   |   2017-09-06 12:00:00.000   |
| 100  |  YES   |   2017-09-06 11:59:59.900   |   2017-09-06 12:00:00.000   |
| 1500 |  YES   |   2017-09-06 11:59:58.500   |   2017-09-06 12:00:00.000   |
| 100  |   NO   | **2017-09-06 11:59:59.900** |   2017-09-06 12:00:00.000   |
| 1500 |   NO   | **2017-09-06 11:59:58.500** |   2017-09-06 12:00:00.000   |
```

Anything that has `PickMe`=`'NO'` shouldn't be included. Also note the displayed dates are rounded and they cause an incorrect `DATEDIFF()` calculation.

NOTE: I hate dates.

Answer (score 1):

Another option...

```
SELECT 
    *,
    SecsDiff = DATEDIFF(ms, td.Created_dtm, td.Update_dtm) / 1000.0
FROM 
    #TestData td
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(ms, td.Created_dtm, td.Update_dtm) BETWEEN 100 AND 1500;
```